# Unable to add jQuery to an angular cli project

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular-cli

I want to use jQuery in my angluar cli project.
I have tried the instructions here: https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to

1. Install jQuery

   ```
   npm install --save jquery;
   ```
2. Install jQuery type defination for type checking.

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
   ```
3. Add refenece of jquery file in "scripts" array inside
   angular-cli.json file.

   ```
   "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
   ]
   ```
4. Import jquery in my app.component.ts file

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app';
     test = jQuery("body");
   }
   ```

However, when a do a `ng build` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts (2,25): Module ''jquery'' resolves
to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

If I remove the `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';` and `ng build' I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts (10,10): Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
```

Not sure where to go from here.

**Update 1**

Based on what @Saravana posted.
If I just do `declare const $: JQueryStatic` and `ng build`, I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts (2,19): Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.
```

but if I do what Saravana suggested on his first post before he deleted it.

```
import "jquery"; 
declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

It builds without complain. So I think Saravana you should revert your post back.

Answer (score 3):

Since the jQuery library adds a the global variables `$` and `jQuery`, you can just declare the variable:

```
import "jquery"; 
declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to the latest cli, created a new project, and moved my bits in and the instructions outlined above worked just fine.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```